# Respawning Enemies by score

Tags: android, surfaceview

i have this generator of enemies by random. i want to change their spawn according to score attained. for example my normal enemies spawn everytime and when my score hits 100 normal enemies still appear but there are harder enemies which spawns.. any hint?

here is my code for random generating of enemies

```
private int getRandomEnemy() {
        /*int randNumber = enemyGenerator.nextInt(150);
        if (randNumber < 70)
            return R.drawable.b1;
        else if (randNumber >= 139 && randNumber < 150)
            return R.drawable.b2;
        else if (randNumber >= 123 && randNumber < 138)
            return R.drawable.b3;
        else if (randNumber >= 117 && randNumber < 122)
            return R.drawable.b4;
        else if (randNumber >= 96 && randNumber < 116)
            return R.drawable.b5;
        else if (randNumber >= 90 && randNumber <= 95)
            return R.drawable.b6;
        else
            // n < 100, always holds
            return R.drawable.bigger;*/
    }
```

i have tried this

```
if(score < 100)
            return R.drawable.b1;
        else if(score >= 100)
            return R.drawable.bigger;
        else 
            return R.drawable.b2;
```

but in this approach after you hit 100 the b1 enemy is not appearing anymore.
thanks~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

b1 is not being created after score > 100 because your logic dictates that it should only spawn b1 when score < 100. Instead of returning only a single type you might consider adding your drawable items into a generic list then returning this list.

eg.

```
List<Drawable> enemies = new List<Drawable>();

if (score < 100)
    enemies.Add(R.drawable.b1);

else if (score >= 100)
{
    enemies.Add(R.drawable.b1);
    enemies.Add(R.drawable.bigger);
}

else
{
    enemies.Add(R.drawable.b2)
}

return enemies;
```

Please note this is not the exact logic as I do not know what the common object is that is driving your drawable objects, I just assumed it would be called drawable, but it may be (and probably is) something else.

Comment: i tried this i changed new List<Drawable>() to ArrayList<Drawable>();
but im having problems with enemies.add | enemies.Add ..The method add(int, Drawable) in the type List<Drawable> is not applicable for the arguments (int) thats what it is saying~

Comment: you need to determine the object type of your drawable items, as I mentioned Drawable is probably not their base class. If you show me an example of you assigning to b1, bigger and b2 then I can help create a more specific example.